# Is there a way to prevent the loadingTemplate from showing up on "fast" routes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Most of the time, my search returns so fast that it's not worth flashing the loading template to the user...(in fact, it's distracting, as people are fine with a blank screen if the results are coming a split second later)...Is there any way to prevent the loading template from showing if the waitOn is only waiting for a short amount of time?

Here's my configuration

```
  Router.route('/search', {
    waitOn: function () {
      return searchSubsManager.subscribe("search", Session.get('searchString'));
    },
    action: function () {
      this.render('searchResults');
    }
  });
```

I saw that with this package:
https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress
you can control whether it shows up for fast routes, but I don't need all that functionality, nor do I want the progress bar it provides... I'm just wondering if the basic iron router/ waitOn functionality can provide this ability.

Comment: You could put display:none on the loading template and make it appear with settimeout always after 500ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not configuration to use on the `waitOn` function, but Why don't you create another layout template, and use it to show that fast routes?

```
<template name="noLoading">
  {{> yield}}
</template>

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('fastRoutes', {
  path: '/someRoutes',
  template: 'myHomeTemplate',
  layoutTemplate: 'noLoading',
  });
});
```

**Update**

or use the [sacha:spin package](https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin) and change the class name depending on the duration of the query.

```
if(queryDuration){
 Meteor.Spinner.options = {
    className: 'none'
  }
}else{
  Meteor.Spinner.options = {
    className: 'spinner'
  }
}
```

Comment: because it's a single route "search" that sometimes is fast, and sometimes is slow, depending on what the user searched for.  I would like it to be shown only if waiting for more than 300 milliseconds, for example...

Comment: I think there is not such a configuration available on the waitOn function, instead you can use the [sacha:spin package](https://atmospherejs.com/sacha/spin) and change the speed to 3seconds or 5

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but where do I put the Meteor.Spinner.options = {} code?  I put it in my javascript and it crashed...

Comment: `if(Meteor.isClient)` or inside the `/client` folder, also be sure that you installed `meteor add sacha:spin`

Comment: thanks... changing the speed didn't help.  and for your other suggestion of using "queryDuration" I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: You say you want to avoid the loading template to render based on some query right? So i assume you already hace the idea about how to calculate tue time(ms) of tht query,

Comment: all I have is a call to .subscribe in the waitOn section... I think the bottom line is that it is not supported directly, as it is with the other progress bar (iron-router-progress) I mentioned in my question.  I believe that once I'm in the waitOn method, it will already be showing the spinner, so I will have no way to add up the time it took to return from the subscribe call to determine whether or not to set the classname option...